# Passing scanned QR content to PHP

Tags: php, vue.js, qr-code

I have a QR code scanner that already works using Instascan and Vue.js libraries. Now what I want to do is to automatically post the scanned content to a php file and redirect to that php file after scanning, but I can't seem to pass the value. Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="form-group" id="app">
        <label v-for="scan in scans" class="disptext" style="font-size: 30px; top: 73%; left: 45%;">Welcome, </label>
        <input v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content" class="form-control" id="qr_user" name="qr_user" placeholder="Scan User QR Code" :value="scan.content" style="width: auto; font-size: 30px; left: 37%; text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 80%; border: 0; background: transparent;">
        <input type="hidden" name="qr" id="qr" :key="scan.date" />
    </div>
```

I tried posting it through my js file like this:

```
    mounted: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview'), scanPeriod: 5 });
    self.scanner.addListener('scan', function (content, image) {
        self.scans.unshift({ date: +(Date.now()), content: content });
        $.post("scanquery.php", {qr: content});
        window.location.assign("scanquery.php");
    });
```

But php executes first so "qr" is always undefined. How can I do this?

**Edit**

Here is the php code, I just posted it by calling the "qr":

```
    $user = $_POST['qr'];
    if(!empty($user)){
        echo $user;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your php code as well?

Comment: Already edited it, Sir.

Comment: You can output debug messages in PHP:  http://php.net/manual/en/debugger.php . If $_POST is not set to anything, I think you have a mismatch in payload formats.

Comment: I tried to use var_dump() and print_r() to verify the content of the $_POST and all returned 0 or null.

Answer (score 0):

You can defer execution of `window.location.assign()` until after the post completes by using a callback in `$.post`:

```
$.post("scanquery.php", {qr: content}, () => {
    window.location.assign("scanquery.php");
});
```

I think you have a mismatch in your payload types.  $.post is formatting your object as JSON, and $_POST is not made available for JSON posts.

This source (https://davidwalsh.name/php-json) notes how to process incoming data as JSON:

```
# Get JSON as a string
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');

# Get as an object
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
```

Someone more of an expert on PHP can correct me on this part.

Comment: It still says undefined. I'm not sure if I am doing this right. Here is my php code:

        $user = $_POST['qr'];
if(!empty($user)){
 echo $user;
}
Am I retrieving it right?

Comment: Have you validated that ```content``` and ```image``` are valid before calling ```$.post```?

Comment: Yes, I have. I displayed the content's value via console.log() and it definitely returns the QR code content.

Comment: Ok, we need to see your php code.  I suspect it has to do with how you're passing the parameters.

Comment: Can you validate that ```$_POST``` is actually set correctly on the PHP side?  It's only set for you under certain conditions.

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I do that, Sir?